# Broadcast::channel callback function is not called

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-echo

I have a problem where event is properly fired, but the data is not returned from authorization callback function inside `Broadcast::channel` method.

The event looks like this:

```
public function __construct($userId, $message, $username, $profileImg, $fixtureId)
{
    $this->message = $message;
    $this->username = $username;
    $this->profileImg = $profileImg;
    $this->userId = $userId;
    $this->fixtureId = $fixtureId;
}
```

The channel (presence) is created and broadcasted like this:

```
public function broadcastOn()
{
    return new PresenceChannel('fixture-channel.' . $this->fixtureId);
}
```

Then in `BroadcastServiceProvider` class, I call this:

```
public function boot()
{

    Broadcast::routes(['middleware' => ['auth']]);

    require base_path('routes/channels.php');
}
```

The `channels.php` file where the problematic function is, looks like this:

```
Broadcast::channel('fixture-channel.{fixtureId}', function ($user, $fixtureId, $message, $username, $profileImg, $userId) {
    DB::table('test')->insert(array('id' => '4'));
    return [
        'message' => $message, 
        'username' => $username, 
        'profileImg' => $profileImg, 
        'userId' => $userId, 
        'fixtureId' => $fixtureId
    ];
});
```

As you see, I'm trying to insert some data inside the callback function, but that never happens. Outside the callaback function, the data is successfully inserted. I also tried with a callback function where only `user` and `fixtureId` are defined - no success.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the `channel.php` is for [Authorization Logic](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/broadcasting#defining-authorization-callbacks).

Where you return data is [`broadcastWith()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/broadcasting#broadcast-data) - or if you don't have `broadcastWith()` method, public properties will be pushed.

It should be something like:

In `channels.php`, it's for authorization of the socket channel, so it should return a boolean.

```
Broadcast::channel('fixture-channel.{fixtureId}', function ($user, $fixtureId) {
    return $user->canAccess($fixtureId);
    // this should return a boolean.
});
```

The rest are fine to be done in construct. Whatever of your properties are defined as public will be pushed.

```
public $message;
public $username;
// etc..

public function __construct($userId, $message, $username, $profileImg, $fixtureId)
{
    $this->message = $message;
    $this->username = $username;
    $this->profileImg = $profileImg;
    $this->userId = $userId;
    $this->fixtureId = $fixtureId;
}
```

---

Optionally, let's say you want to push only `message` and `username`, then use `broadcastWith()`.

```
public function broadcastWith() {
   return [
     'message' => $this->message,
     'username' => $this->username
   ]
}
```

---

If the purpose is writing in database when a message is broadcasted, you can just put it in

```
public function broadcastOn()
{
    \DB::table('test')->insert(array('id' => '4'));

    return new PresenceChannel('fixture-channel.' . $this->fixtureId);
}
```

Comment: Well, if you look at the Laravel Broadcasting documentation, they do it exactly like I did it, tho I agree, that your way looks nicer. The problem is, that the authentication code is never called. I think it is because the Echo.join method is not trying to connect to the channel - No idea why though.

Comment: Did you find out why it's not being called? have the same problem

Comment: Did you put `Log::info('xx')` and see if it actually gets called? That might be an issue. Also the channels.php route should return a boolean.