# Laravel boadcastWith return nothing

Tags: php, laravel, events

When I request to server it returns nothing or sometimes shows:

> argument #1 is not array

When I put dd in `broadcastWith` it shows data but it doesn't return anything. How can I fix this?

This is my controller:

```php
    namespace App\Http\Controllers;
    use App\Message;
    use App\Events\MessageEvent;
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;

    class MessageController extends Controller
    {
        public function index(){

         return event(new MessageEvent([1,2,34]));
        }
    }`
```

and my event:

```php
namespace App\Events;

use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class MessageEvent implements ShouldBroadcast
{

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public $data;

    public function __construct($message)
    {
        $this->data = $message;
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn(){
        return ['message'];
    }

    public function broadcastAs(){
        return 'messageEvent';
    }

    public function broadcastWith(){
    return $this->data;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1) `broadcastOn()` should return a channel instance.

```
public function broadcastOn() {
   return new PresenceChannel('messages');
   // or PrivateChannel() 
   // or Channel()
}
```

2) All the `public` properties will be returned by default so you don't need to have `broadcastWith()` method unless you want to manipulate the data. So unless you want to do something like this:

```
public function broadcastWith(){
   return [
      'myData' => data
   ];
}
```

---

*[In this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59347757/4705339) I explained it in more detail.*

Comment: thanks senty but it didnt work i think this code was working two days ago but now it dosent show me any data in postman i just want to get data

Comment: yes,i think got it. i must request in my client side,shit i forgot it.it toke me 7 hours

Comment: :D yes you need to return `response()->json($data)`

Comment: sorry i kill your time, i got it now.

Comment: I have a problem when I want to debug code I put a dd('test') in broadcastOn function but it doesn't work. or in channel.php file. is it normal?